# Minimum number of pixels per digit for the human eye?

Tags: pixels

How many pixels per digit do I need for the huhman eye to be able to recognize that digit?

I need to cover a rather big area and identify ID codes. The digits are 10 cm high and maybe 8 cm wide. With the current solution I have only 34 pixels per meter, which I assume is not enough. What figures do I need to be able to do the identification?

Comment: This depends on the visual acuity of the viewer and the font being used more than anything else, I'd think.  Sounds like this is on electronic signage?

Comment: What distance will it be viewed from?

Comment: This question seems more about the human side of the problem than a hardware or software issue.